# How do you use the Date&Time trigger for specific times?

Tags: if-this-then-that

The "Every day at" trigger for Date&Time only has the following four options for minutes; :00, :15, :30, and :45. Is there a way to modify this trigger to be accurate to the minute. :37 for example?

Comment: That's for Twitter, but other actions could be used.

Comment: Right, but this the "every day at"  trigger so it would only happen daily so the Action rate doesn't matter.